# Chart.js Customize tool tip to show more data

Tags: svg, chart.js

I'm using the Chart.js 2.0 
The formula : Failure Rate:  Failure Count / Total Count.
I've got the an array for failure rate, failure count and total count.

Plotting failure rate of a component against time in a line chart is straight forward but now i also want the failure count and total count to be displayed when the user hovers over the tool tip. I'm not able to figure out how to customize it.

we have e.time, e.count, e.failure_count, e.rate

```
 new Chart(document.getElementById(event_id).getContext("2d"), {type: "line", data: 
                    {
                        labels:  e.time,
                        datasets: [

                            {
                                label: "Failure Rate",
                                fill: false,
                                borderColor: "#4caf50",
                                backgroundColor: "#4caf50",
                                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                                pointHoverRadius: 3,
                                data: e.rate
                            }
                        ]
                    }, options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    suggestedMin: -1,
                                    suggestedMax: 6
                                }   
                            }] 
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            custom: function(tooltip) {
                                tooltip.text= "Not working????"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2.0, the callback needs a return.
So basically what you want to do is :

```
custom: function(tooltip) {
    tooltip.text= "Not working????"
}
```

By

```
callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) { return "What you want as a tooltip" }
}
```